# If $R$ is a ring with identity and $a$ is a unit, prove that the equation $ax=b$ has a unique solution in $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So, this was my initial proof:

---

Assume $R$ is a ring, and $a,b\in R$

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be solutions of $ax=b$

Hence, $ax_1=b=ax_2 \Rightarrow ax_1-ax_2=0_R \Rightarrow a(x_1-x_2)=0_R$

Thus, we have $x_1-x_2=0_R \Rightarrow x_1=x_2$, and only one solution exists.

---

Only now did I realize that I can only assume $x_1-x_2=0_R$ from $a(x_1-x_2)=0_R$ if $R$ was an integral domain. I didn't know why they provided that $R$ had an identity or why $a$ is a unit.

Comment: How were units defined? The title is (nearly) exactly the definition of a unit, I know: A unit is a number with multiplicative inverse, so $ax=b$ iff $x = a^{-1}b$.

Comment: Pretty much, a unit is defined as:

Assume $R$ is a ring
Let $a \in R$

If $aa^{-1}=1_r$ for $\exists a^{-1} \in R$

Then $a$ is a unit.

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo $a$ is not a unit in your example

Comment: a unit cannot be a zero divisor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is close to being great. First off, they told you that $R$ is ring with unity because only those can have units. Second, your proof doesn't require knowledge that it is an integral domain. Towards the end, you have

$$a(x_1-x_2)=0$$

Then, because $a$ is a unit, $a^{-1}$ exists, and

$$a^{-1}a(x_1-x_2)=a^{-1}0=0$$

$$x_1-x_2=0\implies x_1=x_2$$

so the solution is unique, as you stated.

Comment: Awesome! I can't believe I missed that, haha

Comment: Haha no worries! Just remember that all fields are integral domains, so once you start to have units in your ring, some integral domain properties should start to show up.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have been given, but I'll throw my 2 cents anyway.

For proving uniqueness you just need that $a$ is *left invertible*, that is, there exists $c\in R$ such that $ca=1$.

Indeed, if $ax_1=b=ax_2$, you get $a(x_1-x_2)=0$. Thus $ca(x_1-x_2)=c0=0$ and therefore $x_1-x_2=0$, because $ca=1$.

Right invertibility of $a$ provides existence: if $ad=1$, for some $d\in R$, then $a(db)=(ad)b=1b=b$, so $db$ is a solution to $ax=b$.

Note that if $a$ is both left and right invertible, then, with the same notation as before, we have $c=d$: indeed
$$
c=c1=c(ad)=(ca)d=1d=d
$$
so left and right inverses are the same and, in particular, unique (because any right inverse must be the same with one left inverse and similarly for the other side). In this case $a$ is called a unit and the unique left and right inverse is denoted by $a^{-1}$.

Comment: You mean to tell me that there can be different inverses of an element in a ring?

Comment: Oh, wait, unless it's a commutative ring, there's nothing preventing that.

Comment: @JonSnow If the ring is not commutative, there can be elements with infinitely many left inverses (and no right inverse, of course). A nice exercise is showing that, if an element has two distinct left inverses, than it has infinitely many of them. When you say “ring” with no qualification, I assume it's not necessarily commutative. Of course, in commutative rings a left inverse is also a right inverse.

Comment: I may try that. I have a question, though, why would said element not have any right inverse if it has infinitely many left inverses?

Comment: @JonSnow If it has both a left and a right inverse, they are the same and unique, as proved in my answer; so the existence of two distinct left inverses prevents existence of a right inverse.

Comment: Oh, that was silly of me. Forgive my stupidity.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be a unitial ring with $a,b\in R$ where $a$ is a unit. Then $ax=b$ if and only if $x=a^{-1}b$. Indeed, if $ax=b$, then $$x=1_Rx=a^{-1}ax=a^{-1}b$$
Conversely 
$$
a(a^{-1}b)=(aa^{-1})b=1_Rb=b
$$

Comment: This doesn't show uniqueness.

Comment: @mathers101 yes it does...

Comment: Can you explain to me why it shows uniqueness?

Comment: @JonSnow, see the solution I posted.

Comment: This solution that $ax=b$ **if and only if** $x=a^{-1}b$. This proves existence and uniqueness.

Comment: Ahh, I see, thanks!

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick, your solution is indeed correct, my bad. I think it's just that at an introductory level, with uniqueness proofs it's nice to see that if you assume two solutions they are in fact equal, as in his proof.

Comment: @mathers101 the problem with that approach is it only proves *uniqueness*. It does not prove *existence*.

Answer (score 2):

If

$ax_1 = ax_2 = b, \tag{1}$

with $a \in R$ a unit, then since we have $c \in R$ with $ac = ca = 1_R$,

$x_1 = 1_R x_1 = (ca)x_1 = c(ax_1)$
$= c(ax_2) = (ca)x_2 = 1_R x_2 = x_2, \tag{2}$

so the solution is unique.  We further note that

$ax = b \tag{3}$

yields

$x = 1_R x = (ca)x = c(ax) = cb; \tag{4}$

the unique solution to (3) is thus $cb$.